# Pygame issue with colliderect and classes

Tags: python, pygame

I have a question concerning the colliderect function and variables embedded in classes and functions in general.

I created "hitboxes" around my important elements (player, finish line, monsters), and I want actions to be triggered when those hitboxes "meet".

I understand that the *colliderect* function from pygame is meant to do that, but somehow I can't implement it.

Could someone explain to me, how I would use the feature in the following code, specifically when the variables I have to call are embedded in separate classes and functions?

Thank you very much, here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, pygame, glob, math
from pygame import *
from random import randint
import time

pygame.init()

h = 600
w = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
jump_height = 0

class finish_line:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 600
        self.b = 200
        self.img_finish = pygame.image.load("finish.png")
        self.update_finish(0)
    def update_finish(self, pos_finish):
        screen.blit(self.img_finish, (self.n, self.b))


class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 11
        self.y = 200
        self.speed = 5
        self.ani_speed_init = 5
        self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
        self.ani = glob.glob("animation/run*.png")
        self.ani.sort()
        self.ani_pos = 0
        self.ani_max = len(self.ani)-1
        self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani[0])
        self.update(0)

    def update(self, pos):
        if pos > 0:
            if self.x >= (w - 100):
                self.x = self.x
            else:
                self.x += self.speed

            self.ani_speed -= 1
            if self.ani_speed == 0:
                self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani[self.ani_pos])
                self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
                if self.ani_pos == self.ani_max:
                    self.ani_pos = 0
                else:
                    self.ani_pos += 1

        elif pos < 0:
            if self.x <= 9:
                self.x = self.x
            else:
                self.x -= self.speed

            self.ani_speed -= 1
            if self.ani_speed == 0:
                self.img = pygame.image.load(self.ani[self.ani_pos])
                self.ani_speed = self.ani_speed_init
                if self.ani_pos == self.ani_max:
                    self.ani_pos = 0
                else:
                    self.ani_pos += 1

        if jump_height == 1:
            if self.y <= 10:
                self.y = self.y
            else:
                self.y -= self.speed
        elif jump_height == -1:
            if self.y >= 500:
                self.y = self.y
            else:
                self.y += self.speed
        rectplayer = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), ((self.x + 10), (self.y + 15), 65, 70), 1)
        screen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
        return self.x, self.y


class monster:
    rectmonster = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 650
        self.c = 200
        self.speed_monster = 0.3
        self.img_monster = pygame.image.load("orange.png")
        self.update_monster(0)

    def update_monster(self, pos_monster):
        if pos_monster == 1:
            self.v = self.v + ((randint(-5, 1)) * self.speed_monster)
            self.c = self.c + ((randint(-1, 3)) * self.speed_monster)
            if self.v >= 660:
                self.v = self.v + ((randint(-2, 0)) * self.speed_monster)
            elif self.v <= 140:
                self.v = self.v + ((randint(0, 2)) * self.speed_monster)
            if self.c <= 140:
                self.c = self.c + ((randint(0, 2)) * self.speed_monster)
            elif self.c >= 460:
                self.c = self.c + ((randint(-2, 0)) * self.speed_monster)

        rectmonster = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), ((self.v + 12), (self.c + 5), 76, 90), 1)
        screen.blit(self.img_monster, (self.v, self.c))

finish1 = finish_line()
player1 = player()
monster1 = monster()
monster2 = monster()
pos = 0
pos_monster = 1
pos_finish = 0

while 1:
    screen.fill((255, 204, 229))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0,), (610, 210, 200, 180), 1)
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pos = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = -1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_LEFT:
            pos = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_UP:
            jump_height = 1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_UP:
            jump_height = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_DOWN:
            jump_height = -1
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_DOWN:
            jump_height = 0

    finish1.update_finish(pos_finish)
    monster1.update_monster(pos_monster)
    monster2.update_monster(pos_monster)
    player1.update(pos)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `player` has no size property. It's also not a sprite? `colliderect` is never used in your code, where did you try and implement it?
There's a bunch of code here and gfx applications need to, but I skimmed through it and it looks like you haven't defined any height/width properties to either of your classes, there for it will be extremely hard to check for collisions with `colliderect`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  I cleared the part where I tried to implement it. I defined the size of my objects with the pygame.draw.rect function in the end of each classes code. Does that not work? I wanted to implement colliderect in the While-Loop in the end and check for collisions there, is that a good idea? Thanks again!

Comment: create in Player and Moster `self.rect` using ie. `self.img.get_rect()` and use `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y` to keep position. Then you can use ie. `player.rect.collidrect(monster.rect)` to check collision. BTW: `pygame.Sprite()` uses `self.image` to keep image and `self.rect` to keep size and position - and then `pygame.sprite.Group` uses `self.image`, `self.rect` to check collisions and draw on screen. So `self.image` and `self.rect` can be usefull later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my two cents on the problem based of two comments above.

You're assuming `pygame.draw.rect` automatically gives your class a size property, it does not.
You store the return value of `rect()` in `rectplayer` like so:

```
rectplayer = pygame.draw.rect(...)
```

And I bet `rect()` returns `None` to begin with. Besides that the variable isn't stored as `self.rectplayer` so it's a local function variable not a class-owned variable - so Pygame can't check against it.

This is an easy mistake to make and if that was the only root to the problem here, it would be an easy fix.

Unfortunately there's more assumptions here, such as the fact that `colliderrect` is a global function of `Pygame`.

### colliderect & What is sprites?

There's a key note on this **internal** function of `Pygame` that states:

> all sprites must have a “rect” value, which is a rectangle of the
>   sprite area, which will be used to calculate the collision.

It's a internal function called by [pygame.sprite.spritecollide()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) that mentions the fact that you should be using **Sprites**.

Here's a minimal example of a sprite object:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

       self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
       self.image.fill(color)

       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

At the bottom of the initialization process of this sprite we define our rectangle `self.rect` that contains our `(start_x, start_y), (width, height)` data. These are size properties that you haven't defined in your above example.

Most likely, you could define something along the lines of:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = ...
```

But remember, your `<class player>` has no function called `spritecollide()` or `collide_rect()`, these functions is a inheritance either from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` or `pygame.Surface`, so you're better off sticking to these as your inherited object for your custom classes.

See my above example of `class Player(...)` how to do that.

I know this doesn't solve your entire code base, but hopefully it will give you some sense or idea of what's needed to complete your code.

### End note

A friendly reminder, if you ever think that something is done for you - double check it. Assuming a class gets size properties because you drew a rectangle, check if your class actually did.

```
player1 = player()
print(dir(player1))
```

Is there anything in there remotely resembling `width`, `height`, `size` or `rectangle`? If not, this should indicate where something is funky.